# Error mysql prepare($query) spatial geometry point, how can I insert or update and extract lat lon

Tags: php, mysql, geometry, point

In PHP, I'm trying to store the lat and lon in a mysql database:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET location=ST_GeomFromText(?, ?) WHERE username=?";

$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
 ($stmt = $db->prepare($query))
    || fail('MySQL prepare', $db->error); //GIVES AN UNEXPLAINED ERROR

$spot="POINT($lat $lon)";
$srid="4326";

 $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$spot, $srid, $username)|| fail('MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
```

But it gives an error at prepare. How do I construct this query?

Comment: There is no function `ST_GeomFromText` in mysql.

Comment: What's the point of `stmt_init()`? Also, you're binding 4 parameters on 3 placeholders.

Comment: 3, I edited the question. @sectus, so how can I insert / update a POINT like this?

Comment: The error is just this: MySQL prepare, db->error is not showing extra info